# complex analysis : Growth

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

Let $f$ holomorphic on $C$.

I'm looking for a counter exemple to : If $\sup_{|z|=r} |Re(f)| = O(r^{d})$ then $\sup_{|z|=r} |f| = O(r^{d})$

Actually, I'm wondering if I can find a entire function such as the growth of the real part is lower than the growth of the imaginary part.

Thank you for reading me :).

Answer (score 3):

It is a beautiful fact about entire functions that there is no counterexample to your claim! This is the [Borel—Carathéodory theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Carath%C3%A9odory_theorem). (In the formulation on that web page, take $R=2r$ to deduce the exact form of your claim.)